# Ansible: Manually SSH into machine using inventory from command line?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I seem to remember there is a way to SSH into a machine using the inventory but I can't seem to find it.

I know I can run commands i.e

```
ansible -i hosts mymachine -m ping
```

but rather than doing

```
ssh root@1.1.2.3 for example.
```

Isn't there something like

```
ansible-ssh -i hosts mymachine
```

So using my existing inventory to SSH into a machine, saves me from remembering it all. I could put each value in the ssh config but in the back of my mind, I remember something that you could do on the command line but using the inventory but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Does anybody know if this is possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing with `ansible-console`? This is far from being an interactive ssh session though...

Comment: Related: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10495/using-ssh-to-open-interactive-session-in-ansible

Answer (score 2):

Create the aliases on your own. For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_11
test_12
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
```

Parse the output of *ansible-inventory* by [*jq*](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) and get the remote hosts and ansible users

```bash
shell> ansible-inventory --list | jq -r '._meta.hostvars|keys[]'
test_11
test_12
test_13
```

```bash
shell> ansible-inventory --list | jq -r '._meta.hostvars[].ansible_user'
admin
admin
admin
```

Write a script that creates the aliases

```bash
shell> cat ansible-ssh-alias.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

ahosts=(`ansible-inventory --list | jq -r '._meta.hostvars|keys[]'`)
ausers=(`ansible-inventory --list | jq -r '._meta.hostvars[].ansible_user'`)

elements=${#ahosts[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$elements; i++)); do
    echo alias ansible_${ahosts[${i}]}=\"ssh ${ausers[${i}]}@${ahosts[${i}]}\"
done
```

Test the script

```bash
shell> ./ansible-ssh-alias.sh
alias ansible_test_11="ssh admin@test_11"
alias ansible_test_12="ssh admin@test_12"
alias ansible_test_13="ssh admin@test_13"
```

Execute the output of the script and take a look at the aliases

```
shell> eval "$(./ansible-ssh-alias.sh)"
```

```bash
shell> alias | grep ansible_
alias ansible_test_11='ssh admin@test_11'
alias ansible_test_12='ssh admin@test_12'
alias ansible_test_13='ssh admin@test_13'
```

Now, use the aliases to ssh to the remote hosts. For example,

```bash
shell> ansible_test_11
```

Fit the names of the aliases to your needs.